# Convert foreach loop into array using laravel5

Tags: laravel, foreach

```
@foreach($users as $user)

$users[] = $user->name; 

@endforeach
```

I want to get the output like this.

```
['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'C'];
```

Note: i need this because i have to use this in JavaScript function.

Comment: _"i need this because i have to use this in JavaScript function"_ - then use `json_encode`.

Comment: Can you show how you intend to use it with javascript? Also, I'm assuming `$users` is an Eloquent Collection?

Comment: Thank you for the comment.How can i get rid of these quotes in js now.
[&quot;A&quot;,&quot;B&quot;,&quot;] @CBroe

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.2 @RossWilson

Comment: Did one of the posts below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't "turn a foreach loop into an array", you would **use** that foreach loop to get an array as outcome. In this case I wouldn't go with a foreach approach, there are some methods that can help you cleaning out your code a bit.

You have two options depending on the type of the `$users` variable, [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) or [array_column()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_column.asp):

```
// $users is a collection
json_encode($users->pluck('name'));

// $users is an array
json_encode(array_column($users, 'name'));
```

The `json_encode()` is highly recommended (as the comments pointed out) if you are going to use that output in your javascript. Now you can just send it in a respond and use it as a normal JSON.

In case you print the resulting variable using Blade, remember you need to use `{!! !!}`, otherwise, if you use `{{ }}` you would get unwanted scaped characters, since it uses `htmlspecialchars()` function under the hood.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I am able to convert it into json,but i am getting this output [&quot;A&quot;,&quot;B&quot;,&quot) instead of ['A','B']

Comment: I presume you are using blade to print the json, just use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}` to print the variable.

Comment: @KhiradBanu Glad it helped you!

Comment: @KhiradBanu If it solved your problem, please consider accepting the question so other people can find it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend You should perform this action in your controller only, and then pass it to your view as

```
$userNames=implode(",",array_column($users,'name')); 
return view('your_view',['userNames'=>$userNames]);
```

Then split it in your js as

```
var names="{!! $userNames!!}";
var names= names.split(",");
```

Comment: Why use `<?php echo` when he states that he is using blade and laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Collections will automatically be converted to `json` when you try to echo them.

The reason you're seeing `&quot;` is because using `{{ }}` will automatically escape strings for your protection. You can prevent this by using `{!! !!}` instead.

Try something like this:

```
<script>

    var data = '{!! $users->pluck('name') !!}';

    console.log( JSON.parse(data));
</script>
```

Hope this helps!